# Submit button not working?

Tags: php, html, forms, button

I have this small test page trying to mess around and figure out PHP code, from what I understand, after filling the forms and hitting submit, something should happen. Depending on what you entered.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP Testing Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        echo "Testing Page, working great!\n";
        $theDate = date("M-d-Y ");
        echo "Today is " . $theDate;
        $email1 = $_POST['email1'];
        $email2 = $_POST['email2'];
        function checkEmail()
        {
            $email1 = $_POST['email1'];
            $email2 = $_POST['email2'];
            echo $email1;
            echo $email2;
                if($email1==$email2)
                {
                    echo "\nE-Mail Addresses match.";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "\nCheck to make sure your E-Mails match";
                }
            }
        ?>
        <form name="checkingEmail" action="." method="post">
            E-Mail: <input type="text" name="email1" value="E-Mail Here" />
            <br />
            Retype E-Mail: <input type="text" name="email2" value="Confirm E-Mail" />
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="checkEmail()">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

After the forms are filled (via visiting page) and the Submit button is clicked, nothing happens. Can someone explain please?

*************EDIT****************FIXED*******
Found a work around! No functions, works like a charm.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>PHP Testing Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
        echo "Testing Page, working great!\n";
        $theDate = date("M-d-Y ");
        echo "Today is " . $theDate;
    ?>
    <form name="checkingEmail" action="test.php" method="post">
        E-Mail: <input type="text" name="email1" value="E-Mail Here" />
        <br />
        Retype E-Mail: <input type="text" name="email2" value="Confirm E-Mail" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <?php 
    $email1 = $_POST["email1"];
    $email2 = $_POST["email2"];
    if($email2==null)
    {
/*I believe this just stops it from checking the rest of the conditions, that
        way it won't echo anything until someones enters valid (non-null) input*/
        $email2 = "notnull";
    }
    else if($email1==$email2)
    {
        echo "Good Job.";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "Failure to comply.";
    }
    ?>
</body>
```

I have the check outside of a function, so I don't have to call it or anything like that. Also, with the first if statement, if $email2 is null (When they first load it) it will
simply change $email2 to "notnull" and stop checking statements because it found a valid
one. (Not 100%)

Answer (score 4):

Where is your submit button ?

```
<input type="button" value="Submit" onClick="checkEmail()">
               ^
```

The type should be `submit`

As mentioned on this answer comments, you can't call a php function from javascript.

When you do it you'll call `checkEmail` from a javascript, which isn't defined.
So, you'll get the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: checkEmail is not defined
```

Comment: You didn't mention that he's trying to call a php function from javascript?

Comment: @SamDufel Let's do it step by step ;)

Comment: Oh silly me! Thank you. Also, on the click I am being sent to my home page. I would not like that... What about this function now?

Comment: @TheWalkingPacifist You have to create a javascript function that validate it. You can simple google it. There're many demos that show how to do it.

Comment: Ugh, this is too much for one day. I'll look for it tomorrow. If you could post a helpful link or something whilst I'm gone that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

type should be submit;

If you change it to the submit and then run it, it should be fine. You should use submit type with Form elements.